# Name is nonexistent or not a directory

Tags: matlab, qsub

I'm running an array job (`400` Matlab R2018b tasks) in the HPC of my university. After having `qsub` the .sh file in the terminal, the `400` tasks start by they are immediately killed.

In the .o file of each task no errors are reported but only the following warning

```
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory:
/share/apps/.../NAG/mbl6a24dnl/mex.a64
```

---

In case it might be useful to know: I call the MOSEK solver in my Matlab .m file. In particular, at the beginning of my Matlab .m file I have

```
addpath /share/apps/mosek-9.2/9.2/toolbox/r2015aom
```

Also, this is my .sh file

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_vmem=7G
#$ -l tmem=7G
#$ -l h_rt=480:0:0
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y

#Run 400 tasks 
#$ -t 1-400

#$ -N count2
date
hostname


#Output the Task ID
echo "Task ID is $SGE_TASK_ID"

/share/apps/matlabR2018b -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "main; ID = $SGE_TASK_ID; f; exit"
```

Provided that I have contacted the administrator to ask about this (no reply yet), is there anything I can do can in the immediate to fix it and run my code?

Comment: /.../ is not a valid part of a pathname (unless you really have a link in there called ...). I assume this is an ellipsis that you should replace by an actual directory (possibly a version number of matlab).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant sorry, the pathname is fine, I just did not report it here.

Comment: I assumed you posted the error message verbatim: the missing file is `/share/apps/.../NAG/mbl6a24dnl/mex.a64` although the report may elide long names itself. I see your cross-post in StackOverflow, and it seems probable your PC has this NAG library installed and your Uni HPC does not.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Thanks. Can I ask whether this warning can cause my tasks to be killed? I would like to know whether it is just a warning  and hence the error is somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know MatLab at all: I was just pointing out that the warning message remarks on a very specific filename.

When I google for mexa64, it always comes up as a file extension .mexa64, never as mex.a64. So there may be some ambiguity in a filename somewhere.

There is a NAG Installers note at "www.nag.co.uk/doc/inun/mb24/l6idml/in.html" which includes the pathname: /opt/NAG/mbl6i24dml/mex.a64/a00aa.mexa64; which may explain something, as both variations are in there.

I also wondered why this is a warning, yet processes get killed. It seems that .mexa64 is a code library, and MatLab will try to compile it from source if it can't find it. So maybe, after the warning, it tries to build the library, and records a failure somewhere else (or fails to report it). Possibly the source is also not available or not found correctly.

I hope your Uni administrator knows more than I do. It seems likely you would not have permissions to rectify this issue on the server in any case.